# Vertically align content in a fluid DIV

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/g6puyohg/

**EDIT** Sorry for the confusion, my goal is to vertically align the `button` inside the second `DIV`. Something like [this](http://i.gyazo.com/2e9b639d639aa20ab9d7824b22d6d94b.png).

I don't want to define a fixed `height` to the second `DIV`, since I want it to support different screen sizes (desktop and mobile).

I have tried with the `display: table;` method and didn't work because it requires a fixed height.

Comment: Do you want the second div to go under the first one?

Comment: what, specifically, are you trying to vertically align?

Comment: No idea what you really want to do. Could explain what you are expecting

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've edited the question with more information.

Comment: Did any of [the best ways](http://stackoverflow.com/q/396145/87015) work for you?

Comment: @SalmanA Nope. All because of the `height`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [CSS Flexible Box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), now vertical alignment is possible even in **unknown** heights.

> **[8.3 Cross-axis Alignment: the align-items and align-self properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)**
>
> [Flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) can be aligned in the [cross axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#cross-axis) of the current line of the
>   flex container, similar to [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) but in the perpendicular
>   direction. [`align-items`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-items) sets the default alignment for all of the flex
>   container’s items, including anonymous flex items.
>
> **center** value:
>
> The flex item’s margin box is centered in the cross axis within the line. (If the cross size of the flex line is less than that of the flex item, it will overflow equally in both directions.)

Hence, you coud add an additional class to `.row`<sup>1</sup> element with the following declarations:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/g6puyohg/4/)**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row vertical-align"> <!-- 
             Here --^                 -->
        <div class="col-xs-6"> ... </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

For further reading (including browser support) you could refer to resources below:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/

---

<sup>1. You don't really want to alter all Twitter Bootstrap's rows, do you?</sup>

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work as good as I initially thought. When the space gets smaller the content (in this case the button) get's out of both DIVs (parent and the one that contains the button). [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/tVbNjxH.png). And if you change `col-xs-6` to `col-sm-6` you'll see the fluid layout doesn't work too well (same as tables), it should create a new line instead of compression the content at a certain size.

Comment: @rekt `...the content get's out of both DIVs` I couldn't reproduce it, it would be great if you could demonstrate the issue on jsfiddle. However about the second issue, you could limit `.vertical-align` selector to be applied on a specific screen size by using `@media` queries like so: onhttp://jsfiddle.net/hashem/g6puyohg/6/

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want the button vertically aligned.

You can use an actual table, check this updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g6puyohg/3/

The code :

```
<div class="row">
    <table style='width:100%'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Header X</h2>
                    <h4>Header Y</h4>
                    <p>
                        Text X
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <b>Bold X</b>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Line X</li>
                            <li>Line Y</li>
                            <li>Line Z</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button X</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I do believe that he wants a tabless layout

Comment: There's two problems with that, you'd need to add `class="col-md-6"` to the table `<td>` instead of the `DIV`, and it doesn't work too well with the fluid layout, since is squeezes and never goes to a new line when the space gets too small.